# Does it mean anything if port 1434 UDP is enabled?

Tags: sql-server, udp, firewall

If I do a default install of SQL Server, is the UDP port 1434 (for use with SQL Browser) opened by the installer? Or doI need to to open that up myself?

In other words: if UDP port 1434 is open, can I draw the conclusion that a named instance is installed?

Comment: The installer has no access to your firewall's setting. If if's closed, you'll need open it yourself.

Comment: Can you put that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does not have access to your firewall config and cannot change any firewall rules at all.

You will have to explicitly open the port if you need it open/listening.

Also you mentioned Named instance using this port. If you are expecting named instance to use port 1434, you need to explicitly configure your named instance to use the port 1434 (not recommended 1434 is usually used by the browser and DAC account).

If you do not explicitly configure your named instance to use a specific port and there is already a Default instance of SQL Server installed on the server, by default the Named Instance will use dynamic port range 60000-61000.

Best practice is to explicitly configure your named instance to use a specific port and use ports which are not being used by any other SQL Server services.